# Docker : is it possible to make two Docker containers logging on the same file?

Tags: docker, docker-container, docker-volume, docker-image

i have ***two Dokcer containers***.

Logs for each container are written on a file **a.txt**

**ContainerA**  --> **/VolumeA/a.txt**

**ContainerB**  --> **/VolumeB/a.txt**

I wannt to unify the logging in the same file and the same volume  , so i'm intending to mount a same **SharedVolume** for both of the containers , and output logs for the same **a.txt** file :

***Intented*** **Result** : VolumeA **OR** VolumeB  ---> **/SharedVolume/a.txt**

My problem , is that idon't know if each container , **will erase or write in the end of file** when logging.

> Of course my purpose is to find a way to make the logging , **at the
>   file end** every time.

Also *i haven't a problem of concurrent access* , since **ContainerA** is logging always before **ContainerB**

**Suggestions ?**

Comment: Can you talk more about why you want / need to do this?

Comment: @johnharris85 i want to centralize my containers logging , i need to use the whole , log file within another platform , to generate some logging dashboards , with only one input

Comment: Can [Docker Logging Driver](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/) help you?

Comment: I'd like to turn @juanlumn's question into a statement: you should be using a logging driver to collect your logs and deliver them to a central location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mount same volume to more than one container. Example:

`$ docker run -di -v mynewvol:/logdir busybox 'echo first > /logdir/logfile && cat -v'
$ docker ps
862068e5f930        busybox             "/bin/sh -c 'echo ..."   5 seconds ago       Up 4 seconds                            infallible_roentgen
$ docker run -it --rm -v mynewvol:/logdir busybox /bin/sh -c 'echo second >> /logdir/logfile; cat /logdir/logfile'
first
second`

So this should work out of the box.

Comment: ...except that having two processes trying to write to the same file at the same time without any coordination is probably just going to create a mess.

Comment: @larsks Yes I totally agree that it could be really messy but question ends with info that concurrent access is not a problem. I assumed that he knows what he is doing.

Comment: Ah, right, I missed that bit. I still think that the op would be better off using the logging facilities that are provided by Docker.

Comment: For any production traffic 100% agree, but if this is some dev environment or PoC setup then implementation speed is also important. Normal way would be to setup ELK and use proper log driver in docker.